# Using Apache 2.4, How can I deny access from everyone, except internal IPs?

Tags: apache-2.4, access-control-list

The Order/Allow/Deny directives are [deprecated](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html) (as of Apache 2.4)

So, using the new "Required" directives, how can I allow access to a directory from an internal IP only?

Comment: A simple review of the upgrading documentation would have told you all you needed to know: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Answer (score 4):

It's actually MUCH simpler in Apache2.4!

Let's say that you want PHPMyAdmin to be accessible ONLY on your internal network. You could do something like this

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    AllowOverride None
    Require ip 192.168.1.0/24
</Directory>
```

**AllowOverride None:** Tells Apache that .htaccess files are not allowed to override this rule

**Require ip 192.168.1.0/24** tells Apache that you MUST be on the internal network in order to access this directory. (the `/24` is called CIDR notation and evaluates to the subnet mask 255.255.255.0. More on that [here](https://wiki.xtronics.com/index.php/IP_Subnet_Masks))

That's all there is to it!

(Natrually you will need to replace the IP with one that matches your internal network)